# How to display horizontal p:selectOneRadio pimefaces

Tags: html, css, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i do this the radio button is diplying vertical, I want to display vertically.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="operation" value="#{tradingMobileBean.selectedOperation}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tradingMobileBean.listOperation}" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{tradingMobileBean.operationChangeListner()}" update="stockname" />
 </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: What ? Your title says horizontally but you're saying you want it to display vertically. Which is it ? Have you tried looking at the tag reference ? `layout="lineDirection"` for horizontal and `layout="pageDirection"` for vertical.

Answer (score 10):

Add **layout** attribute with value `pageDirection` which will give the vertical layout. The default value is `lineDirection` which gives you the horizontal layout.

```
<p:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" id="operation" value="#{tradingMobileBean.selectedOperation}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{tradingMobileBean.listOperation}" />
     <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{tradingMobileBean.operationChangeListner()}" update="stockname" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```